# Por que el TextBox me borra texto

Tags: vb

de nuevo con una cuestion, el programa funciona como debe, genera nombres al azar dependiendo de las restricciones que uno le ponga, lo que no quiero es que me borre los textos de los textbox que escribo, el ejemplo lo pongo en imagenes para mayor entendimiento por que no consigo hacer que no se borren los 2 ultimos textbox

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adjunto codigo

```
Public Class Form1
Dim texto1, texto2, texto3 As String
Dim caracter As Char
Dim tam As Integer
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    texto1 = TextBox1.Text
    texto2 = TextBox2.Text
    texto3 = TextBox3.Text

    Label1.Text = texto1
    Label2.Text = texto2
    Label3.Text = texto3
    tam = Len(texto1)

    For i = 1 To tam
        caracter = Mid(texto1, i, 1)
        caracter = Mid(texto2, i, 1)
        caracter = Mid(texto3, i, 1)
        TextBox2.Text = texto2.Substring(0, 1)
        TextBox3.Text = texto3.Substring(0, 1)

        Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text & TextBox2.Text & "." & TextBox3.Text

    Next
    For i = 1 To tam
        caracter = Mid(texto1, i, 1)
        caracter = Mid(texto2, i, 1)
        caracter = Mid(texto3, i, 1)
        TextBox2.Text = texto2.Substring(0, 3)
        TextBox3.Text = texto3.Substring(texto3.Length - 3, 3)

        Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text & TextBox2.Text & TextBox3.Text

    Next

    For i = 1 To tam
        caracter = Mid(texto1, i, 1)
        caracter = Mid(texto2, i, 1)
        caracter = Mid(texto3, i, 1)
        TextBox2.Text = texto2.Substring(0, 1)
        TextBox3.Text = texto3.Substring(texto3.Length - 1, 1)

        Label3.Text = TextBox1.Text & "." & TextBox2.Text & TextBox3.Text

    Next

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cada vez que asignas la propiedad `Text` de un `TextBox`, estás cambiando el valor. Es decir, no se borra solo, tú mismo lo estás cambiando cuando haces una asignación como:

```
TextBox2.Text = texto2.Substring(0, 1)
```

Puedes utilizar otras variables para almacenar y manipular el valor, si las necesitas, y nunca asignar un valor a `TextBox2.Text` ni `TextBox3.Text`, de esa manera se respetará lo que el usuario ha colocado en dichos campos.

#### Edición

Dando una mirada extra a tu código, me doy cuenta que la mayor parte es redundante o simplemente hace operaciones que no tienen ningún efecto en el resultado, así que podría reducirse a esto:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    texto1 = TextBox1.Text
    texto2 = TextBox2.Text
    texto3 = TextBox3.Text

    Label1.Text = texto1 & texto2.Substring(0, 1) & "." & texto3.Substring(0, 1)
    Label2.Text = texto1 & texto2.Substring(0, 3) & texto3.Substring(texto3.Length - 3, 3)
    Label3.Text = texto1 & "." & texto2.Substring(0, 1) & texto3.Substring(texto3.Length - 1, 1)
End Sub
```

En realidad las variables `textoX` no son absolutamente necesarias, pero las dejé porque hacen más legible el código.

Comment: te agradezco el tiempo y las correcciones, muchas graciias